# Cannot dispatch any more messages on lane [0, 0, 0, 0]

Tags: substrate-node-template, xcm, parity-bridges-common

I'm sending  XCM message from one chain to another through Bridge. But i'm facing an issue for receiving the message.

```json
    023-05-31 10:40:30.010 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::bridge-messages: Cannot dispatch any more messages on lane [0, 0, 0, 0]. Weight: declared=Weight(ref_time: 4000000000, proof_size: 262144), left=Weight(ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0)    
    2023-05-31 10:40:30.010 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::bridge-messages: Received messages: total=1, valid=0. Weight used: Weight(ref_time: 365960000, proof_size: 123455)/Weight(ref_time: 365960000, proof_size: 123455)    
    2023-05-31 10:40:30.010 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker run\
```

The function which execute in receiving is this

```rs
    pub fn receive_messages_proof(
                origin: OriginFor<T>,
                relayer_id_at_bridged_chain: T::InboundRelayer,
                proof: MessagesProofOf<T, I>,
                messages_count: u32,
                dispatch_weight: Weight,
            ) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
                ensure_not_halted::<T, I>()?;
                let relayer_id_at_this_chain = ensure_signed(origin)?;
    
                // reject transactions that are declaring too many messages
                ensure!(
                    MessageNonce::from(messages_count) <= T::MaxUnconfirmedMessagesAtInboundLane::get(),
                    Error::<T, I>::TooManyMessagesInTheProof
                );
    
            
                let declared_weight = T::WeightInfo::receive_messages_proof_weight(
                    &proof,
                    messages_count,
                    dispatch_weight,
                );
                let mut actual_weight = declared_weight;
    
                // verify messages proof && convert proof into messages
                let messages = verify_and_decode_messages_proof::<
                    T::SourceHeaderChain,
                    T::InboundMessageFee,
                    T::InboundPayload,
                >(proof, messages_count)
                .map_err(|err| {
                    log::trace!(
                        target: "runtime::bridge-messages",
                        "Rejecting invalid messages proof: {:?}",
                        err,
                    );
    
                    Error::<T, I>::InvalidMessagesProof
                })?;
    
                // dispatch messages and (optionally) update lane(s) state(s)
                let mut total_messages = 0;
                let mut valid_messages = 0;
                let mut dispatch_weight_left = dispatch_weight;
                for (lane_id, lane_data) in messages {
                    let mut lane = inbound_lane::<T, I>(lane_id);
    
                    if let Some(lane_state) = lane_data.lane_state {
                        let updated_latest_confirmed_nonce = lane.receive_state_update(lane_state);
                        if let Some(updated_latest_confirmed_nonce) = updated_latest_confirmed_nonce {
                            log::trace!(
                                target: "runtime::bridge-messages",
                                "Received lane {:?} state update: latest_confirmed_nonce={}",
                                lane_id,
                                updated_latest_confirmed_nonce,
                            );
                        }
                    }
    
                    for mut message in lane_data.messages {
                        debug_assert_eq!(message.key.lane_id, lane_id);
                        total_messages += 1;
    
                        // ensure that relayer has declared enough weight for dispatching next message
                        // on this lane. We can't dispatch lane messages out-of-order, so if declared
                        // weight is not enough, let's move to next lane
                        let dispatch_weight = T::MessageDispatch::dispatch_weight(&mut message);
                        if dispatch_weight.any_gt(dispatch_weight_left ){
                            log::trace!(
                                target: "runtime::bridge-messages",
                                "Cannot dispatch any more messages on lane {:?}. Weight: declared={}, left={}",
                                lane_id,
                                dispatch_weight,
                                dispatch_weight_left,
                            );
                            break
                        }
                        total_messages += 1;
    
                        let receival_result = lane.receive_message::<T::MessageDispatch, T::AccountId>(
                            &relayer_id_at_bridged_chain,
                            &relayer_id_at_this_chain,
                            message.key.nonce,
                            message.data,
                        );
    
                    
                        let (unspent_weight, refund_pay_dispatch_fee) = match receival_result {
                            ReceivalResult::Dispatched(dispatch_result) => {
                                valid_messages += 1;
                                (
                                    dispatch_result.unspent_weight,
                                    !dispatch_result.dispatch_fee_paid_during_dispatch,
                                )
                            },
                            ReceivalResult::InvalidNonce |
                            ReceivalResult::TooManyUnrewardedRelayers |
                            ReceivalResult::TooManyUnconfirmedMessages => (dispatch_weight, true),
                        };
    
                        let unspent_weight = unspent_weight.min(dispatch_weight);
                        dispatch_weight_left -= dispatch_weight - unspent_weight;
                        actual_weight = actual_weight.saturating_sub(unspent_weight).saturating_sub(
                        //  // delivery call weight formula assumes that the fee is paid at
                        //  // this (target) chain. If the message is prepaid at the source
                        //  // chain, let's refund relayer with this extra cost.
                        if refund_pay_dispatch_fee {
                            T::WeightInfo::pay_inbound_dispatch_fee_overhead()
                        } else {
                            Weight::zero()
                        },
                    );
                    }
                }
    
                log::trace!(
                    target: "runtime::bridge-messages",
                    "Received messages: total={}, valid={}. Weight used: {}/{}",
                    total_messages,
                    valid_messages,
                    actual_weight,
                    declared_weight,
                );
    
                Ok(PostDispatchInfo { actual_weight: Some(actual_weight), pays_fee: Pays::Yes })
            }
```

**On sending message i'm getting this log**

```json
    2023-05-31 10:40:12.011 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::bridge-messages: T::OnMessageAccepted callback has spent less weight than expected. Refunding: Weight(ref_time: 125000000, proof_size: 0) - Weight(ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0) = Weight(ref_time: 125000000, proof_size: 0)    
    2023-05-31 10:40:12.011 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::bridge-messages: Accepted message 1 to lane [0, 0, 0, 0]. Message size: 87    
    2023-05-31 10:40:12.011 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::bridge: Sent XCM message [0, 0, 0, 0]/1 to [112, 101, 101, 114]: [167, 96, 230, 244, 244, 220, 186, 46, 0, 142, 206, 231, 18, 60, 1, 107, 131, 115, 253, 63, 45, 38, 187, 97, 175, 149, 137, 34, 34, 220, 141, 64]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the modules according to new WeightV2, there might be some modules left in your code that needs to be udpated.